# git not found on git extension even by specifying right path

Tags: git, git-extensions

I'm trying to set my git Extension but I get this error all the time, even by specifying the right path to my git exe and bin, i'm desperate !
on the other hand i have seen that opening git extension as admin and specifying the right path to the git.exe make the issue goes away.

what can i do to resolve this ?
[image]

Comment: Maybe you install and run git with admin permission?

Comment: It might be related to some permissions ... but I don't know how to resolve it :(

Comment: have you tried adding git's install directory to PATH? can you run git from cmd/terminal?

Comment: I have added my git to Path variable system too yes, and when starting git from cdm it does not open actually !